# Unit testing Web API Controller: Error fetching result

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest, assert

I'm new to unit testing in ASP.NET so please forgive my ignorance on this. I'm trying to test my controller.

This is the function in my controller which I'm testing:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCustId(string name)
{
    var c_id = db.Customer.Where(s => (s.c_Name == name));

    if (c_id == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Ok(c_id);
}
```

And this is my unit test code:

```
public void GetName_ShouldReturnCorrectId()
{
    var context = new TestSContext();
    context.Customers.Add(new Customer { c_ID = 1, c_Name = "jonny"});

    var controller = new CustomerController(context);
    var result = controller.GetCustId("Johnny") as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Customer>;  //ISSUE: Result is always NULL

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Content.c_ID);
}
```

The issue is here:

```
var result = controller.GetServiceId("Johnny") as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Customer>
```

because it is always returning NULL.

BUT... If I use just this:

```
var result = controller.GetCustId("Johnny");
```

Then the result is not null. And the first assert passes.

But I can't use it because I'm not sure how to check the second assert statement without using `result.Content`. I'm really not sure what are the best practices to be testing in my case.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't understand the section about `GetServiceId`; you wrote that `GetCustId` is the method you are trying to test... about the first assert, you can remove it, the second assert will make the failure if the result is null... What is the problem with `result.Content`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find `"Johnny"` (with 'h') when you have put `"jonny"` into your mock `context` thus method always returns `null` due to your if statement

```
if (c_id == null)
{
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @nizzik's answer, which is correct based on your example, to avoid simple mistakes like that you should store your values in variables and reuse them to make sure that they are as intended.

```
public void GetName_ShouldReturnCorrectId() {
    //Arrange
    var name = "Johnny";
    var expectedId = 1;
    var context = new TestSContext();
    context.Customers.Add(new Customer { c_ID = expectedId, c_Name = name});    
    var controller = new CustomerController(context);

    //Act
    var result = controller.GetCustId(name) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Customer>;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedId, result.Content.c_ID);
}
```

That way you can change any one of them and the test should execute as expected.